# Convert twitter UTC format in excel

Tags: python, excel, twitter

When I extract date and time from twitter, I get this format:

```
Mon Jun 17 14:44:40 +0000 2013
```

how do I convert it in excel to any of the excel formats? I need to do this because I want to use if statements in excel

I have excel 2003

The pic below shows that if I try to convert with excel, excel sees a different date.

[image]

Comment: This is one of excel-supported format.

Answer (score 1):

Is the day field always two characters ? 
If so, you can use this  (assuming the date is in cell F20

```
=DATE(RIGHT(F20,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(1 & MID(F20,5,3))),MID(F20,9,2))
```

You can format the date to the format you currently have by selecting a custom format and entering the date mask

```
ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss "+0000" yyyy
```

however, I think your dates are coming in as strings so you'll need to parse it out as above.